# why does yield get skipped when using send method

Tags: python, generator, yield

```
guests = ["Tim,22",
"Tonya,45",
"Mary,12",
"Ann,32",
"Beth,20",
"Sam,5",
"Manny,76",
"Kenton,15",
"Kenny,27",
"Dixie,46",
"Mallory,32",
"Julian,4",
"Edward,71",
"Rose,65"]

def read_guestlist(file_name):
  while True:
    for person in guests:
      name, age = person.split(",")

      new_guest = yield name
      if new_guest != None: 
        new_name, new_age = new_guest.split(",")
        name = new_name
        yield "This never gets printed"
        yield new_name

guestlist = read_guestlist(guests)

counter = 0
for name in guestlist:
  if counter == 5:
    guestlist.send("Jane,35") 
    counter += 1 
  elif counter == 10:
    guestlist.send("Pontus,35")
    counter += 1
  print(name)
  counter += 1
  if counter > 17:
    break
```

I have been playing around with this code for a while, and each time I have sent a value using `send` one `yield` gets skipped. In this case it is the `yield`: `yield "This never gets printed"`. My question is: why does that particular `yield` get skipped each time I use `send` method?

Comment: It isn't skipped. Try printing `guestlist.send("Jane,35")`.

Comment: The function has a `file_name` parameter which is never used in the function. Was that intentional?

Comment: If you check [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator.send): _... The `send()` method returns the next value yielded by the generator ..._ It's a bit like using `next()` on a generator. Try `print(guestlist.send("Jane,35"))`.